# Kafka consumer consuming message multiple times

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a Kafka consumer C1 in a consumer group CG1,subscribed to topic T1.Recently I observed some weird behavior with it.Though message is getting published to Topic T1 only once,it is getting consumed multiple times.It seems that Consumer C1 is taking more time to process than max.poll.interval.ms which was 5 minutes.Then I increased this property to 20 minutes.And still I can observe C1 is getting mesage after every 10 minutes.Why it is not taking new time 20 mins ?

Comment: Please add more details like Kafka version, environment etc. There are three different scenarios by which you can process messages at consumer end 1. At most once 2. At least once 3. Exactly once. It seems you are looking for the third one.

Comment: Kafka 0.11,Os- Centos.Yes i am looking for exactly once delivery

Comment: What (other) consumer properties have you added to achieve that? Please show a [mcve]. Also the max poll interval is an upper bound, not a set time

Comment: are you committing offset manually? or auto?, have you seen any rebalancing issues?

Comment: @Deadpool yeah I am committing offeset manually.Yes I have seen rebalancing issues.

Comment: @cricket_007 - name: my_topic
      key.deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      value.deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      numOfThreads: 6
      topic.processor: com.mycompany.MyProcessor
      group.id: my_consumer_1
      poll.timeout: 1000